# cURL command to Unity's web request

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a JSON is structured as:

```
{
    "values": {
        "AppName": "Test001",
        "AppUser": "Testttt"
    },
    "consentAccepted": true,
    "consentToken": "adgrtztzEZKo3LD56Hjo8LiqeoQ2Z5+ik0loplr"
}
```

The above JSON works in https://web.postman.co/ and I get status as success.

I would like to try Unity's WebRequest with POST to fill in "AppName" and "AppUser" along with token. How do I achieve this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class SendData: MonoBehaviour {

void Update () {
        if (InputCompat.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.P)) {
            StartCoroutine ("FillAndSend");
        }
    }
public IEnumerator FillAndSend() {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();

        form.AddField ("AppName", "Testttt");
        form.AddField ("AppUser", "Reinnn");

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post ("https://mywebsite.com/profile/MyApp", form);
        www.SetRequestHeader ("token", "tz677zuiuis2qEZKo3Lt+kHluOGss");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest ();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log (www.error);
        } else {
            Debug.Log (www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

I receive an error named as HTTP internal server error. What is wrong with it? Along with this I have to add a certain parameter that is given as:

```
formToken: MyApp
```

Comment: Will it be possible for you to provide information regarding what type of __Authorization__ **token** is expected by the server? Is it a **Bearer** or a **Basic** token?

Comment: Have you tried first via something like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), to understand what sort of values the server is expecting?

Comment: @nIcEcOw yes i have tried in Postman and it works there.

Comment: Are you trying to send a webpage in response to this request? As I am getting a webpage as a response.

Comment: The webpage given above is just a sample. I did not provide the real one for security reasons :D

Comment: Then it appears some actual server URL is required to debug the problem, but I tried to give the `Authorization` token to the link given and it seems to work, but since you referred that is not the original server so I am in doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like instead of a `form` you rather want to send a JSON string.

Something like

```
var json = "{\"values\": {\"AppName\":\"Test001\",\"AppUser\":\"Rein\"}, \"consentAccepted\":true, \"consentToken\":\"tz677zuiuis2qEZKo3Lt+kHluOGss\"}";
var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

using (var www = new UnityWebRequest("https://mywebsite.com/profile/MyApp", "POST"))
{
    www.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonBytes);
    www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", " text/plain");
    
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

in order to easily configure this e.g. via the Inspector or passing in the values without having to deal with writing the JSON manually you could easily have a class like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class PostData
{
    public Values values;
    public bool consentAccepted;
    public string consentToken;
}

[Serializable]
public class Values
{
    public string AppName;
    public string AppUser;
}
```

and then simply do e.g.

```
var jsonData = new PostData
{
    values = new Values
    {
        AppName = "Test001",
        AppUser = "Rein"
    },
    consentAccepted = true,
    consentToken = "tz677zuiuis2qEZKo3Lt+kHluOGss"
}
var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(jsonData);
var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
```

Comment: Tried that as well still the same bad request :/

Comment: @Rein Try composing the entire request from scratch .. I think I've seen this stuff before and for some reason you need to go raw bytes

Comment: Sorry still no luck :( I tried your second solution as well and getting Bad Request. I even tried updating the token to latest one. (I can use it as long as it is not older than an hour)

Comment: @derHugo: IMHO, It seems half of the work done by you is simply done by Unity itself while creating an instance of `UnityWebRequest` via [UnityWebRequest.Post ( ... )](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html). No need to convert to bytes, it is done internally by `UnityWebRequest.Post  (...)`. Seems much to me about `Authorization` token problem.

Comment: @nIcEcOw well kind of but since OP specifically specified the `Content-Type: application/json` I guess it is relevant to do so ... when using the normal `UnityWebRequest.Post` is rather uses `ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and url escapes the passed `string` which afaik would break the JSON but maybe I'm wrong here ... usually it would expect a string like e.g. `"user=Bla&password=Blip"` .. not a JSON string with special characters .. afaik for JSON you kinda need to go via raw bytes

Comment: Hmm I tried the POST in postman and it works there. Something wrong with Unity code? I have updated my question. Or could be that the JSON structured in Unity is wrong?

Comment: @derHugo if you need to send JSON, just create an instance via `UnityWebRequest.Post ( string URL, string jsonString )`, and then set the header to `application/json`, that will do. What you referring to is done, when we pass `WWWForm` instead of `string` to the form data.

Comment: @nIcEcOw no afaik the API mentions under the `string, string` version that it uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as well and escapes the string: `The data in postData will be escaped, then interpreted into a byte stream via System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` so using `Post` will not work for JSON directly .. you need the raw bytes before it gets escaped

Answer (score 2):

The user derHugo's solution is right except that the JSON structure in the code was wrong. I fixed it and here is the complete solution.

```
private string json = @"{
        'values': {
        'AppName': 'Test001',
        'AppUser': 'Rein'
    },
    'consentAccepted': true,
    'consentToken': 't65wRU6rttK1klzu768'
    }";

var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

using (var www = new UnityWebRequest("https://mywebsite.com/profile/MyApp", "POST"))
{
    www.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonBytes);
    www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", " text/plain");
    
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: tbh I don't really see at what point that JSON now has a different structure